# ngTable with angular-routing = undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs-routing, ngtable

Please help. I am stuck at this point for more then 14 hours and I can't find an explanation or an example.

This is what I have now:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PaYR7c0QXSKxl1jcmRBQ

If I don't use angular-routing, ngTable works correctly. As soon as I add routing, it gives this error.
The error disappears when I comment $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
...but then the data is not showing.

The code that does not work:

```
    var app = angular.module('main', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngTable'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

app.controller('MyCtrl1', [function($scope,ngTableParams) {
  var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });   
  }]);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="main">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant section of your code directly into your question so that security-conscious users (or users with security-conscious employers) don't have to wonder about the content of your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML header should be corrected:  (you were loading ngTable before angular)

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
<script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>
```

The controller declaration is a little off.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'ngTableParams', function MyCtrl1($scope, ngTableParams) {
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the correct declaration. For anyone interested in the full example, http://plnkr.co/edit/KRCAe3j8KnT000RQ24vu?p=preview